# Get data if nullable relationship field using EF Core query in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core based website. I want to get data using EF Core query in such a way it return value even it is null. I want to get data including `OrderNumber` and `ItemName` event `OrderID` is null. I have tried with following query but it only shows 2 records which have `OrderID`.

Please advice:

Query:

```
var FilteredTransactionData = (from tr in _Context.Transactions
                               join or in _Context.Orders on tr.OrdersID equals or.OrdersID
                               join it in _Context.Items on tr.ItemID equals it.ItemID
                               select new
                                      {
                                          TransactionID = tr.TransactionID,
                                          ItemName = it.ItemName,
                                          OrderNumber = or.OrderNumber,
                                          TransactionQuantity = tr.TransactionQuantity,
                                      }).ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class Transactions
{
    public long TransactionID { get; set; }
    public long ItemID { get; set; }         //Relationship 
    public long? OrderID { get; set; }         //Relationship 
    public decimal TransactionQuantity { get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{
    public long OrdersID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Transaction table

```
TransactionID   |   ItemID  |   OrderID     |   TransactionQuantity
----------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------------
1                   101         Null                10
2                   102         Null                12
3                   103         201                 20
4                   101         202                 20
5                   102         Null                10
```

Required output

```
TransactionID   |   ItemName    |   OrderNumber |   TransactionQuantity
----------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------
1                   Item101                             10
2                   Item102                             12
3                   Item103         Order201            20
4                   Item101         Order202            20
5                   Item102                             10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
join or in _Context.Orders on tr.OrdersID equals or.OrdersID
```

Here you are joining two tables by `OrdersID`. That is why Null OrdersID rows are being ignored. That is the actual behaviour of joining.

What you need to do is left join the `Transactions` table to the `Orders` table. In that case rows from  `Transactions` table all rows will be picked even if the `OrdersID` us Null.

You can write the query in this way:

```
var FilteredTransactionData = from tr in _Context.Transactions
                join or in _Context.Orders on  on tr.OrdersID equals or.OrdersID into gj
                from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                   TransactionID = tr.TransactionID,
                   ItemName = it.ItemName,
                   OrderNumber = or.OrderNumber,
                   TransactionQuantity = tr.TransactionQuantity,
                }).ToList();
```

Note the selection `into gj` above and then selecting the Null rows with `gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`